# Aggregation by Foreign Key and other field in Django Admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I'm working in Django and having an issue displaying something properly in my Admin site. These are the models

```
class IndexSetSize(models.Model):
    """ A time series of sizes for each index set """
    index_set = models.ForeignKey(IndexSet, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    byte_size = models.BigIntegerField()
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField()

class IndexSet(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=4096)
    # ...  some other stuff that isn't really important
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.title}"
```

It is displaying all the  appropriate data I need, but, I want to display the sum of IndexSetSize, grouped by the index_set key and also grouped by the timestamp (There can be multiple occurrences of an IndexSet for a given timestamp, so I want to add up all the byte_sizes). Currently is just showing every single record. Additionally,  I would prefer the total_size field to be sortable

Current Admin model looks like:

```
class IndexSetSizeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    """ View-only admin for index set sizes """
    fields = ["index_set", "total_size", "byte_size", "timestamp"]
    list_display = ["index_set", "total_size", "timestamp"]
    search_fields = ["index_set"]
    list_filter = ["index_set__title"]

    def total_size(self, obj):
        """ Returns human readable size """
        if obj.total_size:
            return humanize.naturalsize(obj.total_size)
        return "-"
    total_size.admin_order_field = 'total_size'

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        queryset = super().get_queryset(request).select_related()
        queryset = queryset.annotate(
            total_size=Sum('byte_size', filter=Q(index_set__in_graylog=True)))
        return queryset
```

It seems the proper way to do a group by in Django is to use .values(), although if I use that in get_queryset, an error is thrown saying `Cannot call select_related() after .values() or .values_list()`. I'm having trouble finding in the documentation if there's a 'correct' way to values/annotate/aggregate that will work correctly with get_queryset. It's a pretty simple sum/group by query I'm trying to do, but I'm not sure what the "Django way" is to accomplish it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you would be able to return the full queryset and group by `index_set` in `get_queryset` as you can't select all columns but group by an individual column in sql

```sql
SELECT *, SUM(index_size) FROM indexsetsize GROUP BY index_set   // doesn't work
```

You could perform an extra query in the `total_size` method to get the aggregated value. However, this would perform the query for every row returned and slow your page load down.

```py
    def total_size(self, obj):
        """ Returns human readable size """
        return humanize.naturalsize(sum(IndexSetSize.objects.filter(
                                        index_set=obj.index_set).values_list(
                                       'byte_size', flat=True)))
    total_size.admin_order_field = 'total_size'
```

It would be better to perform this annotation within the `IndexSetAdmin` as the `index_set` will already be grouped through the reverse foreign key. This will mean you can perform the annotation in `get_queryset`. I would also set the `related_name` on the foreign key on `IndexSetSize` so you can access the realted `IndexSetSize` objects from `IndexSet` using that name.

```py
class IndexSetSize(models.Model):
    index_set = models.ForeignKey(IndexSet, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='index_set_sizes')
    ...

class IndexSetAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...

    def total_size(self, obj):
        """ Returns human readable size """
        if obj.total_size:
            return humanize.naturalsize(obj.total_size)
        return "-"

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        queryset = super().get_queryset(request).prefetch_related('index_set_sizes').annotate(
            total_size=Sum('index_set_sizes__byte_size')).order_by('total_size')
        return queryset
```